# Lazy collection in Spring JPA with Jackson and elasticsearch wihtout jsonignore

Tags: json, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-elasticsearch

We have spring boot with elasticsearch and mysql. We have a feature for reindexing all data from the mysql into elasticsearch, which is simple as:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class SearchIndexer {

    public void reindex(){
        elasticsearchRepository.save(jpaRepository.findAll());
    }
}
```

Now we have an entity called invoice, which has a lazy loaded collection with a "derived" calculation:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "invoice")
@Document(indexName = "invoice")
public class Invoice implements Serializable {

     //... other props

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "invoice")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<InvoiceItem> invoiceItems = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    // getter and setters for invoiceItems

    public boolean isAllSimple() {
        if(getInvoiceType()==null){
            return false;
        }
        if(getInvoiceItems()==null){
            return false;
        }
        for(InvoiceItem item : getInvoiceItems()){
            if(!item.isSimple()){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

When the rest-controller is used, the resulting json contains correctly a property "allSimple". This is, because we run that with hibernate5module in one transaction.

However, when we call `elasticsearchRepository.save(jpaRepository.findAll())` (also in a transaction), the objectmapper for elasticsearch cannot serialize the "allSimple" property, beacause of a `LazyInitializationException`. The elasticsearch-objectmapper is configured as follows:

```
@Bean
public ElasticsearchTemplate elasticsearchTemplate(Client client, Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder, Hibernate5Module hibernate5Module) {       
    return new ElasticsearchTemplate(client, new CustomEntityMapper(jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.createXmlMapper(false).modulesToInstall(hibernate5Module).build()));        
}

public class CustomEntityMapper implements EntityMapper {

    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public CustomEntityMapper(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;    
        objectMapper.configure( DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);     
        objectMapper.configure( DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);
    }        

    @Override
    public String mapToString(Object object) throws IOException {
        return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(object);
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T mapToObject(String source, Class<T> clazz) throws IOException {
        return objectMapper.readValue(source, clazz);
    }
}
```

The hibernate5module is loaded and registered, but did not solve the problem. 
Normally we would add a "JsonIgnore" to that property, but we need that value, so this is no option. 
Any ideas?!

Answer (score 0):

I had a project configurated with this.

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.sagasoftware.tracker.*")
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {

        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter messageConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Hibernate5Module hibernate5Module = new Hibernate5Module();

        objectMapper.registerModule(hibernate5Module);
        objectMapper.configure(FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
 objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY);

        messageConverter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);

        return messageConverter;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
        super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
    }

}
```

If you are using spring boot, declaring the bean MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter and registering the hibernate5module should fix your problem.

I could render a entity throught a rest controller.

Comment: I already have a MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter, but this is used for rest controllers (as i said, these ones are working without problems) and not used by elasticsearch...

Comment: could you update your question and add where you use the elasticsearchRepository.save(jpaRepository.findAll())?.

Comment: updated it - it is only one method in a service class, which is called by a rest-endpoint